# Why does my iterator not iterate throught all values?

Tags: rust, cryptography

I am doing this challenge: https://cryptopals.com/sets/1/challenges/5

```rust
fn encrypt(message: &str, key: &str) -> String {
    let mut encrypted_message: Vec<u8> = message.as_bytes().to_vec();
    println!("{:?}", encrypted_message);
    for (index, ch) in key.char_indices() {
        encrypted_message
            .iter_mut()
            //.inspect(|byte| {print!("{}, ", *byte);})
            .skip(index)
            // .inspect(|byte| {print!("{}, ", *byte);})
            .step_by(key.len())
            .inspect(|byte| {print!("{}, ", *byte);})
            .for_each(|byte| *byte = *byte^(ch as u8));
        println!("");
    }
    println!("{:?}", encrypted_message);
    let mut encrypted_string = String::new();
    encrypted_message.iter().for_each(|num| encrypted_string+=&format!("{:02x}", *num)[..]);
    encrypted_string
}
```

In this function, I noticed that the iterator in the for loop does not iterate throught all values.
As can be seen in this output:

```
---- tests::encryption_test stdout ----
[66, 117, 114, 110, 105, 110, 103, 32, 39, 101, 109, 44, 32, 105, 102, 32, 121, 111, 117, 32, 97, 105, 110, 39, 116, 32, 113, 117, 105, 99, 107, 32, 97, 110, 100, 32, 110, 105, 109, 98, 108, 101]
66, 110, 103, 101, 32, 32, 117, 105, 116, 117, 107, 110, 110, 98, 
117, 105, 32, 109, 105, 121, 32, 110, 32, 105, 32, 100, 105, 108, 
114, 110, 39, 44, 102, 111, 97, 39, 113, 99, 97, 32, 109, 101, 
[11, 54, 55, 39, 42, 43, 46, 99, 98, 44, 46, 105, 105, 42, 35, 105, 58, 42, 60, 99, 36, 32, 45, 98, 61, 99, 52, 60, 42, 38, 34, 99, 36, 39, 39, 101, 39, 42, 40, 43, 47, 32]
thread 'tests::encryption_test' panicked at 'assertion failed: `(left == right)`
  left: `"0b3637272a2b2e63622c2e69692a23693a2a3c6324202d623d63343c2a26226324272765272"`,
 right: `"0b3637272a2b2e63622c2e69692a23693a2a3c6324202d623d63343c2a26226324272765272a282b2f20"`', src/main.rs:33:9
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace


failures:
    tests::encryption_test

test result: FAILED. 0 passed; 1 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 0.00s
```

I am expecting the variable `encrypted_message` not to become smaller

Comment: skip will skip character not octet, and so skip(index) make no sense

Comment: So I should use key.bytes().enumerate()?

Comment: I think a fairly idiomatic solution would look like this: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=80cd8e80b86728e486d522c94ccc8f7d

Comment: @Stargateur `encrypted_message` is a `Vec<u8>`, so `skip` does skip bytes, not characters. However `key.len()` is a number of characters, not bytes. You probably want to do `let key = key.as_bytes();` at the top of the function, so that key will be a `&[u8]` (and use `key.iter().enumerate()` instead of `key.char_indices()`).

Comment: @IvanC Your solution gives the same wrong answer as my program

Comment: I found the problem, the problem was my testing since i cut each sentence by themselves